# Is it possible for an SCCM client to stop a particular client update?

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, sccm-2012-r2

I really don't want to get a particular update SCCM push from IT. I have local admin rights on my windows 7 machine. Is there a way for me to prevent the update from applying. I can see it in Software Center but cannot see a way to decline the update.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. SCCM is a centralized management control tool, users should obey the management of the IT sector strategy. Current situation you could communicate with IT departments.

Comment: I see your point; however I have already attempted talking to IT and got nowhere. I believe I am more than capable of supporting myself and just need to be left alone this once.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: Is that answer from technology point of view?

Comment: Technically， you could  decline the all update by edit the Registry keys, which is possible but is not recommended：
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate

Comment: i am really only concerned about one particular update

Comment: After I discuss with our WSUS guy, they give me a way. You can have a try: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/145843/block-specific-windows-update-hotfix/341318#341318)